# jinja2 cannot import name 'select_autoescape'

Tags: python, cgi

i am going crazy with an import problem. It should be 'simple' because i have a script (test2.py) with this import inside:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader,select_autoescape

    def myfun(arg1)
       ...

       env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('/var/www/html/templates'),autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']))
       ...
```

Note that this script test2.py is called by test1.py (called by a CGI scripr) like that :

import test2

test2.myfun(arg1)

then i get the error:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader, select_autoescape
ImportError: cannot import name 'select_autoescape'
```

the crazy thing is that if i call (directly) another script with these imports:
    from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader,select_autoescape

it goes fine! it does import the select_autoescape thing ...

So my question is why does it not import it when i call it from another function/module?

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling jinja2:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade jinja2
```

It worked for me.